# pass the data-id attribute value to a controller method using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a button element which has a data-id attribute.I need to to send the data-id to a controller method in codeigniter using jquery ajax post method.I don't have any form .But the ajax request i made can not enter into the controller method .What might be the reason and how i can solve this issue?in my config file i set the base url and rewrite the index.php using htaccess file  :

***I do get alert('success') after clicking the button***

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/'
```

admin controller:

```
 class Admin extends CI_Controller{


         public function processReq(){
            $this->load->view('admin/processReq');

         }

   }
```

button( no form element) :

```
<button type="button" data-id='approved' class="approved buttons">Approve</button>
```

ajax method:

```
 $(".buttons").click(function(event){
     var status=$(this).data('id');

     $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('admin/processReq') ;?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            status: status
        },

        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
             var error=xhr.responseText;
             alert(error);
          }
    });
 });
```

[image]

Comment: What does `xhr.responseText` yield?

Comment: nothing..i mentioed in my queston that i get alert('success') from success..

Comment: If you set the `dataType:html` in your ajax object, do you get it back? Also, what does the Network inspector show?

Comment: added the response after datatype :html in my post

Comment: console.log(data) in the success and see if it even is a success

Answer (score 0):

You get the alert because the controller sent the browser a reply with a server code of 200. That header response code tells AJAX to call the `success` function. `$this->load->view('admin/processReq');` is where the OK (code 200) came from.

This controller shows another way to handle this so that you can react based on the reply from `processReq()`.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('admin/processReq'); //if this really is the view file
  }


  public function processReq()
  {
    $status = this->input->post('status'); 
    //I am assuming that data('id') is '1' or '0' since you
    //don't describe what it actually is I had to make something up.
    if($status === '1'){
      echo json_encode(array('results' => 'success')) ;
    }else{
      echo json_encode(array('results' => 'fail')) ;
    }
  }

}
```

You need to add one ajax option - `dataType: 'json'` - for this to work reliably

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url('admin/processReq') ;?>",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        status: status
    },
```

Your ajax `success` function could do this

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data.results === 'success'){
    alert('success');
  } else {
    alert('success');   
  }
},
```

An alternative way to indicate a failure would be to output a header with a server code in the 400 or 500 (error) range. If you do that then the ajax `error` function will be called. SO has lots of examples of how to accomplish that.